# Understanding graphical representation of Git Extensions Branches

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-extensions

Coming from SVN, I am still getting used to the complexity of Git.  Having discovered first hand that TortoiseGit is just asking for trouble, I am also discovering Git Extensions.

As I have done in the past, I managed to work on three separate tasks before finishing any of them--not so wise, I know.  It lets me practice branching though, that's for sure.

I now have three branches in addition to `master`: `thread-safe`, `common-create-web-request` and `change-alias-target`.  At this point, nothing is unstaged, all changes are committed to one of those three branches (or so I thought, see next paragraph) and none of them has been pushed or merged.

I am just curious, and a little concerned, that the Git Extensions Browse window seems to show graphically that, although the revisions to the branches `thread-safe` and `common-create-web-request` are on those branches, the two revisions to the branch `change-alias-target` are not (I am looking at the graph running up the left side of the list of revisions).  If I mistakenly committed them to.. `master`? then I guess I need to know how to move them to the branch `change-alias-target`, please.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 commits are in the branch 'change-alias-target'. 
Branches in git are pointers that handle a chain of commits. So, if you could see a commit, that's because they are contained in all the branches (the red tags) that you will encounter when following the lines going up.

You could also see in the commit tabs, once you click on its corresponding line, all the branches it is contained in. The list is displayed after the commit message...

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand why the visual representation looks different for `change-alias-target`.

I did do a `git log` from `master` and noticed that those two revisions are not on it, whereas after checking out the branch `change-alias-target` and doing a `git log`, they showed up.  That's comforting but I'd still like to know why the grey tags for that branch are visually on a split-off branch like the other two branches are.

Comment: You should not give sense to how branches are displayed (the rule is not master always in lines and branches on the right because master is in fact a branch like the others). That's an algorithm that render the branches and there is no perfect way to render. In fact, the branch that will be displayed in line will always be the one with the more recent commit. You must look at the topology and not why one is displayed in line and not the others...